# Check if a P tag has an IMG tag with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page with this code :

```
<p>
    <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

How I can select with JS any `<p>` that contain an `<img id="img_2">` :

I tried this but not working :

```
 if $('p:has(img#img_2)'){
    action here
 }
```

Comment: You could find the child and then find the parent.  `$('#img_2').closest('p').length`

Comment: Though the `:has()` may already be working.  You just have to remember to use the `.length` for the if, because all objects are truthy

Comment: You're missing a pair of parenthesis at your if clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Debugging

Your code:

```js
if $('p:has(img#img_2)'){
  action here
}
```

Has the following issues:

- no parentheses around the condition expression
- jQuery object always returns truthy

Corrected:

```js
// .length is used to for detection and results in truthy/falsy expression 
if ( $('p:has(img#img_2)').length ){ 
  action here
}
```

---

## Detecting Parent/Child

Element detection can be easily accomplished natively, without using jQuery.

### 1. Walking-Up

This approach finds an element and walks up the DOM tree.  `closest` and `parentNode` are used to clearly describe intent; since it's desired that the closest `p` is the parent and not some ancestor. In production, you may want to add checks to insure `img` is found before looking for the parent -- a quick way is to add `img &&` at the front of the condition.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('#img_2')

if (img.closest('p') == img.parentNode)
  console.log('found')
  
if (img.closest('p') != img.parentNode)
  console.log('not found')
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

### 2. Walking-Down

This is accomplished by finding the paragraph and searching for it's children.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p')

if (p.querySelector('#img_1'))
  console.log('found 1')
  
if (p.querySelector('#img_2'))
  console.log('found 2')       // not found
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_1">
  <div><img src="path.jpg" id="img_2"></div>
</p>
```

### 3. Trusting Child-Selector

This is using the child `>` selector to retrieve elements and then evaluating if the elements were found.  Provided are both sides of the conditional to illustrate how to detect a non-match.  Generally, the `else` would suffice.

```js
const img1 = document.querySelector('p > #img_1')
const img2 = document.querySelector('p > #img_2')


if (img1)
  console.log('found img_1')                    // not reached
if (!img1)
  console.log('no paragraph with #img_1 child')
  
  
if (img2)
  console.log('found "p>#img_2"; paragraph: ', img2.parentNode)
if (!img2)
  console.log('no paragraph with #img_2 child') // not reached
```

```html
<!-- outside -->
<img src="path.jpg" id="img_1">

<!-- inside -->
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

Comment: @MAZ, `if ( $('p:has(img#img_2)') ){....` surely will not work as `$('p:has(img#img_2)')` will always return an object, putting any object inside the `if` condition in that way will always evaluate to `true`!!!

Comment: @Mamun you're right! I didn't finish my edit, let me fix it; thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the jquery object inside `()`. Also you have to use the *length* property of the object:

```js
if ($('p:has(img#img_2)').length){
    console.log('Exists');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `length` property like:

```js
if ($('p').find('img#img_2').length) {
  console.log('Image found!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

Or,

```js
if ($('p > img#img_2').length) {
  console.log('Image found!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

Or your code should also be working with `()` like:

```js
if ($('p:has(img#img_2)')) {
  console.log('Image found!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

using [> Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) Something like this:

```js
console.log($('p > img#img_2').length);
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p>
    <img src="path.jpg" id="img_2">
</p>
```